# Understand `reporting()` class in N.E.A.T algorithm

Tags: python, neat

i'm making an AI using N.E.A.T algorithm that plays a game, there is a reporting function in this algorithm that shows statistics about every generation, and one of them is about the best genome, i'm trying to understand what is meant by this line `Best fitness: 20201.00000 - size: (4, 7) - species 1 - id 2564`, specially the `size` and `id` part.

When i went to the file of the algorithm,I found out this is the printing sentence

```py
print('Best fitness: {0:3.5f} - size: {1!r} - species {2} - id{3}'
.format(best_genome.fitness, best_genome.size(),best_species_id,best_genome.key))
```

but still, I can't understand what theses two numbers mean

Comment: What Python library are you using?

Comment: it is N.E.A.T library https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/neat_overview.html , the code in the post is from it.

Answer (score 0):

1. The id is simply the ID of the particular genome.
2. And size refers to (as per the docs) :

> Returns genome complexity, taken to be (number of nodes, number of enabled connections); currently only used for reporters - some retrieve this information for the highest-fitness genome at the end of each generation.